# New input cell style with a custom evaluator

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, cells

I'm interested to implement a custom input style which would appear (mostly?) like a normal `"Input"` `Cell`, but which would perform custom evaluation on <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>return</kbd> or when evaluating a cell as a part of a group of cells. I'm interested of the custom evaluator, but also on easy way of creating such cells (keyboard shortcut?) or converting ordinary input cells to this custom variant.

How to approach this problem? My first assumption is that setting `$Pre` and applying custom evaluation on basis of either `Cell` style or `CellTags` values would be the way to go. I'm a little uncertain if this is the most sensible approach since there are also `CellEvaluationFunction` and `CellProlog`. What are the caveats of these approaches?

Comment: `CellEvaluationFunction` seems by far the best approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`StyleKeyMapping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleKeyMapping) to easily switch back and forth from "Input" cells to your "CustomInput" cell. For example:

```
Cell[StyleData["Input"],
    StyleKeyMapping->{
        "=" -> "WolframAlphaShort",
        "*" -> "Item",
        ">" -> "ExternalLanguage",
        "Tab" -> "CustomInput"
    }
]

Cell[StyleData["CustomInput"],
    StyleKeyMapping->{"Tab" -> "Input"}
]
```

For a custom evaluation function, you can use [`CellProlog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellProlog) or [`CellEvaluationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEvaluationFunction). For example:

```
CellEvaluationFunction -> Function @ Replace[#,
    {
    BoxData[foo_List] :> ToExpression[
        BoxData[Map[RowBox[{"goo", "[", #, "]"}]& , foo]],
        #2
    ],
    BoxData[foo_] :> ToExpression[BoxData[RowBox[{"goo", "[", foo, "]"}]], #2]
    }
]
```

would add the wrapper `goo` around every input before evaluation. The one downside with this approach is that only the last line of input will get an output, the others are automatically suppressed. If that is a problem, then I could give you a [`CellProlog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellProlog) approach instead.